# How to Create A node-express-postgresql login page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

So I've looked online for countless hours for a decent tutorial on how to create a simple, login page that will store a user (no password) into a database and when that said user logs in and will find the user in the database and let them log in. I don't want password used and everything I find includes a password. Just was wondering if there was a way without it. Anything helps. If you need to see the code I already have let me know. Also, just a reminder that I want them in a PostgreSQL database. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you just make a simple form with one input text field for username and one submit field. Get the username from req.body.username and then query the database WHERE username = :username. Then add the user in session.

Another approach would be to use a tutorial with a password but not offer an input field for the password for the user to fill but you feed it with a hidden field.

Comment: thats the problem. The the sites I've found used passport middle ware and that is not what I wanted. I've done the hidden field part I just don't know how to  make sure a user is in the database to sign in with